# Can I do an array formula within an array formula in Excel?

Tags: arrays, excel, linear-algebra, array-formulas

Here I have a 4x3 array and a 1x3 array. With the top array, I want to sum by column (creating an intermediate array of 1x3), and multiple the result by the bottom array, then sum the result.

[image]

With this example, summing the large array by columns would produce {9, 17, 15} and multiplying by the bottom array would produce {18, 51, 45}, and summing those three gives a final answer of 114.

Is it possible to put that calculation in a single cell in Excel? I've seen linear algebra functions used to accomplish similar things, but am simply not skilled enough in LA to even know if this is possible. I can't reference each column individually, because there could be any number of columns.

Intuition says SUMPRODUCT could be used here, but I can't seem to work it out.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply multiply the range by the bottom row:

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(A6:C6*A1:C4)
```

As the larger range is iterated it will be multiplied by the appropriate value in the column and added together.

It does `3*2+1*3+1*3+1*2+...`

[image]